# - [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] issue on OSX 10.11 Beta 2

Tags: macos, beta, metal

Whenever I add the `CAMetalLayer` to the `NSView`, the `[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable]` method will pass `nil` after 3 successful `id<CAMetalDrawable>`.

I tried two different ways to configure the setup. One, I used MTKView and used its `CAMetalLayer`, it didn't work. Second, used `NSView` and created new `CAMetalLayer`. That didn't work also. I had weird issues.

I want to know anyone else is having this problem and if anyone know a solution to resolve this.

Additional notes:
I don't want to use MTKView draw system by overriding its methods (not yet). Also this is not a problem on iOS 8 and I didn't tried my code with the beta release of iOS 9 (not yet).

**Update**

I reroute my drawable calls to use the `MTKViewDelegate` delegate. And from the `drawInView` delegate method, I was able to retrieve consistent drawable frames. **However**, I still would like to use the `nextDrawable` method directly from `CAMetalLayer`. Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to come back to this.

This was `fixed` with `OSX Beta 4`. `nextDrawable` method is working correctly and passing back usable `CAMetalDrawable` objects. I guess I should've waited until the release version came out before posting this. I just wanted to let everyone else know about this problem back when the beta version was first released.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, and asked **Metal** devs at **WWDC 15**.

**How `MTKView` works**:  `MTKView` has limited number of drawables (probably 3), so when you are encoding frames there are few drawables you can draw to.

**What you are doing**:  Your scene is probably quite simple, so you CPU can encode frames really fast. So it seems like, when CPU is 4 frames ahead of GPU, you ask for next drawable and since all (3) drawables are in use, it fails.

**Solution**: You need to use ***semapthore*** to wait for drawable when there is no free one.

Here's code to use:

```
let inflightSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(3)

func drawInView(view: MTKView) {

        // use semaphore to encode 3 frames ahead
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(inflightSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        self.update()

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
        let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(view.currentRenderPassDescriptor!)
        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives()


        // use completion handler to signal the semaphore when this frame is completed allowing the encoding of the next frame to proceed
        commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler{ [weak self] commandBuffer in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(strongSelf.inflightSemaphore)
            }
            return
        }

        commandBuffer.presentDrawable(view.currentDrawable!)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }
```

**This is not documented anywhere!** The only written mention of that is in *iOS project template* (File -> New -> Project -> Game -> Pick Metal) in `GameViewController`.

I already filled a radar on this (no response yet), and would appreciate if you do the same https://bugreport.apple.com

Also you may find useful my github repo https://github.com/haawa799/RamOnMetal

Comment: The issue you had, are you talking about `CAMetalLayer` by calling `nextDrawable` or are you talking about `MTKView` drawable method that you file a radar against?

Comment: @NateHat MTKView drawable

Comment: My ordeal was about `CAMetalLayer` not `MTKView`. You probably can use `MTKView`'s `CAMetalLayer`, but the concern is using `nextDrawable` method from `CAMetalLayer` class, from a new instance or from `MTKView`. It's good information that you had pointed out though. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@autoreleasepool` for render in drawable.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15102